# printing character with continue statement in c++

Tags: c++

```
void main()
{
    char ch = 'A';
    while (ch <= 'F')
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
                ch++;
                continue;
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                ch++;
        }
        putchar (ch);
    }
}
```

My question is why does the above code print only FG even when the condition of while loop is less than 'F'. Why does it doesn't print the other character.

Comment: Because that's what your code is doing. What was your expected o/p

Comment: My expected output was ABCEF

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood `continue`. Did you mean `break`?

Comment: What I understand is that continue will skip to print letter D

Answer (score 1):

From `A` to `D` the while loop is continued i.e. whenever while hits continue it goes back to the top `while (condition)`

And when char is `E` it increments the `ch` and `ch` has now `F` which is being put on o/p.

Now the char is `F` in while condition and it increments the `ch` in switch and `ch` has `G` and that is being put on console.

Thus the o/p is `FG`

Also it's worth noting that `continue` statement will execute if `ch` is one of these characters `A`,`B`,`C` or `D` because switch case falls if it has no statements

Comment: Thanks you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` interrupts the loop and starts the next iteration from the beginning.

Your loop is equivalent to

```
  while (ch <='F'){
      if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'B' || ch == 'C' || ch == 'D')
      {
          ch++;
      }
      else if (ch == 'E' || ch == 'F')
      {
          ch++;
          putchar(ch);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - it works the same way as in your program and everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks whether `ch > 'F'` after incrementing and printing it, in other words when `ch = 'G'` has been printed the condition becomes false and the loop terminates.

As for why the other characters aren't printed, well when `ch <= D` it is incremented and the `continue` causes it to skip the `putchar` and jump back to the `while`-statement.

EDIT: Apparently the expected output was `ABCEF`. Keep in mind that without a `break`-statement a `switch-case` just continues to the next case. The value of `ch` determines at what case code starts executing, but unless it finds a `break` statement, it just falls through to the next case.